# GCP-LoadBalancer Changes keep Reverting

Tags: google-cloud-platform, load-balancing

Changes I make to my load balancer on GCP aren't persisting.

Tried using both the UI and Command line.
Noticed it when trying to do two separate tasks:

1) Change the SSL certificate that's being presented for FrontEnd.
My new SSL cert will take effect for a while and after a short time (mins to an hour I'll check again and it will have switched back to preivous SSL cert) This happens even when I delete the old cert from project.

2) Removing HTTP access and only leaving HTTPS. Again changes take effect for only a short while.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 3):

This turned out to be that my API spec I'd loaded had referenced kubernetes secret to put into the loadbalancer.

I was changing the ssl cert manually through the GCP UI - but periodically it was reloading the ingress (api-spec) yaml file and reverting to that cert in the secret.

Answer (score -1):

I am referring you to the articles on [creating an SSL certificate resources](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/ssl-certificates#creating_an_ssl_certificate_resource) and on adding [SSL certificates to configure the proxy](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/content-based-example#configuring_the_load_balancing_service) for HTTPS load balancer (see frontend configuration). Make sure you have followed all the steps properly as described.Please note that you should not use a self-signed certificate for production purposes.

After following all the steps, if the issue still persists, then it could be a bug.In that case, I would recommend to report and file your issue on [public issue tracker](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker/), providing the detail of  issue, as it might require further investigation.